# PARALLELPERIOD 31st back to the 30th creates empty cell

Tags: ssas, mdx

The following measure creates a gap at the end of particular months e.g. 31st of December. It is acting as expected but I didn't foresee this happening when setting up the report.

```
AVG(
PARALLELPERIOD
    (
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],
    1,
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER
    ).PARENT.CHILDREN,
[Measures].[Revenue])
```

In a full script against the AdventureWorks cube I've got the following example:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Mth_DalyAvg] AS
        AVG(
            PARALLELPERIOD(
                [Date].[Calendar].[Month],
                1,
                [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
                ).PARENT.CHILDREN,
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
SELECT
        DESCENDANTS(
            {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[11],
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[12]},
            [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
            )
        ON 1,
        {
        [Measures].[Mth_DalyAvg]
        } ON 0
FROM    [Adventure Works]
```

Produces the following. I'd like to find a way to repeat the same value in the cell for December 31, 2007

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you always use days, then

```
    AVG(
        [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
        .PARENT.Lag(1).CHILDREN,
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )
```

should work.

If there can be other members of the calendar hierarchy like months as well, then it will get more complex.

Comment: +1 that's spot on. I actually ended up with an answer myself which is the same as yours except this bit `[Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.PREVMEMBER.CHILDREN` .....I'm assuming there are no particular advantages to `PREVMEMBER` over `Lag(1)` ?

Comment: I would not think there is a huge difference between `prevmember` and `Lag(1)`, and even `Lead(-1)`, to add another possibility stating the same logic. MDX functions tend to have some overlap of functionality between different functions.

Comment: (p.s. if you ever feel any of my questions are interesting then feel free to up-vote them ... not that I'm chasing points or that the MDX community on here is pretty small)